# Getting some HTML code on response of ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, response

I am making an application.In that application i have one  blank aspx page.That application is deployed on IIS. And i am calling that aspx page from other machine.On the load event of aspx page i written code as

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           

        Response.BufferOutput = false;
        writer = Response.Output;
        try
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {

                processRequest.ProcessReuest(Request, writer);
                writer.Close();

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LoggerWeb.Error(ex.Message,ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            processRequest = null;
        }
    }
```

Where  processRequest.ProcessReuest is the method of another class within same project. In that method i am writing some string data on the response.Many a times i am getting correct data on response but sometimes i am getting some HTML data on response as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
   <form method="post" action="obstreamer.aspx?PortNo=16387&amp;Scode=8&amp;SessionId=04052012073228202&amp;Width=4&amp;historyDirection=backword" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="
2012-05-04 19:34:18.994 MVisum Ob[3270:f803] [self.newdata length]=235
2012-05-04 19:34:18.995 MVisum Ob[3270:f803] RECEIVED DATA=/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZIYNklWIHuNxLNApLWs+6QTn2Vt4n8THjCx316p9WOvX" />

   <div>

   </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting why that data comes on response. Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a much simpler experience would be making these other things into UserControls and then including the relevant UserControl in this page.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I dont want that HTML code on response. I am not getting why this HTML code gets on response?

Comment: @Dany consider using [Generic web handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx)